# JAVA Repeating a process in java and counting the time it took

Tags: java

I created a csv file out of two files. I want to provide an opportunity for the user to enter a number so that the program repeat the process of creating the csv file.

So if a user enter 5 e.g. the program repeats the process 5 times and prints out the time it took do the process.

Repeating the processing part

```
    int Numofrepetition;
    Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in);    
    System.out.println("How many times you want to repeate the process");  
    Numofrepetition =getin.nexLine(); 

    Using 
    Long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis ();
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-t0)/1000.0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis ();
for(int i=0;i<Numofrepetition;i++){
   //TODO creating the csv file
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-t0)/1000.0);
```

The loop is made for that